# Android ViewModel with appCompat v27.0.0

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am trying to use the Android architecture components ViewModel in a project with the latest `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0`. The appcompat already contains everything from `android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3` and `android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0`. However it does not seem to contain for example `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0`which includes the `ViewModel` class. There still does not seem to be a version 1.0.3 of the extensions but if I try using 1.0.0 I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
>   Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.3) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I can fix this like that:

```
implementation ("android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"){
    exclude module: "runtime"
}
```

but this can not be the final solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

LiveData , ViewModel , Room and Paging Library all of these libraries are part of android architecture components . None of these library are part of support library .

To add architecture components as a dependency on your gradle file you need to add them separately and their associate annotation processor like this

```
// Architecture Components
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0'
```

for detail documentation please see the official documentation [adding architecture components to your project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Comment: The official documentation seems to be out of date here. As I stated in my question it was added to appCompat at some point (like 26.1.0 - I do not know the exact version). Try it you have access to all Lifecycle related stuff by just including appCompat 27.0.0. The ViewModel however still only lives in the extensions